# vba to copy selected data to multiple sheets based upon criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below which copies data from one table to three other existing sheets but I also need to copy selected columns of the data to other sheets as a summary and append to the existing data.

There are 9 columns in the table but I only need copy 4 of these to the other sheet.  Column 5 holds the criteria which will be used to split the data and I need to copy columns 1,2,4 and 8.

```
Sub SplitData()

Dim wsInput As Worksheet
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim wsNames As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wsInput = Sheets("Input Sheet")
wsNames = Array("Output 1", "Output 2", "Output 3")
Const FilterColumn = 7

With wsInput
LastRow = wsInput.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 0 To UBound(wsNames)
   Set wsOutput = Worksheets(wsNames(i))
   wsOutput.Cells.ClearContents

       With wsInput.Range("C105:K" & LastRow)
       .AutoFilter Field:=FilterColumn, Criteria1:=wsNames(i)
       .Offset(0, 0).Copy wsOutput.Range("A2")
       End With
   Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

I use the code below to copy other data in the same workbook to another sheet and am struggling to find a method of combining this with a table of data which needs to be copied and split into multiple sheets.

```
Sub CopyExpenditure()

Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet
Dim wsCopyExpTo As Worksheet

Set wsCopyFrom = Worksheets("Input Sheet")
Set wsCopyExpTo = Worksheets("Cash Expenditure List")

LastRow = wsCopyExpTo.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wsCopyFrom.Activate
If wsCopyFrom.Range("F59") = 0 Then
Exit Sub
End If

If wsCopyFrom.Range("G59") > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Row(s) contain a Description but not an amount. Please enter an amount or clear the Description field")
Exit Sub
End If

wsCopyExpTo.Activate
If Range("c" & LastRow) = "Total" Then
Rows(LastRow).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If

LastCopyRow = wsCopyFrom.Range("C57").Row

For x = 37 To LastCopyRow
wsCopyFrom.Activate
LastRow2 = wsCopyExpTo.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("c37:F57").Select
    chkValue = Cells(x, 6).Value
    If chkValue > 0 Then
    Cells(x, 3).Resize(1, 4).Copy
wsCopyExpTo.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("C" & LastRow2 + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End If
Next x

LastRow4 = wsCopyExpTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wsCopyFrom.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("d7").Select
Selection.Copy
wsCopyExpTo.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("a" & LastRow4 + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Range("A10:A" & LastRow4 + 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

wsCopyFrom.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("F7").Select
Selection.Copy
wsCopyExpTo.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("b" & LastRow4 + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

LastRow3 = wsCopyExpTo.Range("c" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

wsCopyExpTo.Range("a" & LastRow2 + 1).Select
Range("a" & LastRow4 + 1 & ":a" & LastRow3).FillDown

wsCopyExpTo.Range("b" & LastRow2 + 1).Select
Range("b" & LastRow4 + 1 & ":b" & LastRow3).FillDown


Range("G10:AB10").Select
Range("A10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G10:AB" & LastRow3), Type:=xlFillDefault

wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 3) = "Total"
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("f11:f" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("g11:g" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 8) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("h11:h" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 9) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("i11:i" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 10) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("j11:j" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 11) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("k11:k" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 12) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("l11:l" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 13) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("m11:m" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 14) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("n11:n" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 15) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("o11:o" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 16) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("p11:p" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 17) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("q11:q" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 18) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("r11:r" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 19) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("s11:s" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 20) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("t11:t" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 21) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("u11:u" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 22) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("v11:v" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 23) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("w11:w" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 24) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("x11:x" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 25) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("y11:y" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 26) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("z11:z" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 27) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("aa11:aa" & LastRow3))
wsCopyExpTo.Cells(LastRow3 + 2, 28) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("ab11:ab" & LastRow3))

With wsCopyExpTo.Rows(LastRow3 + 2)
    .Font.ColorIndex = 1
    .Font.Bold = True
    .NumberFormat = "_-#,###.00_-;_-(#,###.00);0.00_-"
End With

Range("AB10").EntireColumn.Hidden = True



End Sub
```

Would this be best split into two tasks; the first to split the data onto three temporary sheets and the second task to get it into the required format?

Comment: you've shown us only the code you have that works but not any efforts to accomplish the goal stated in your text, nor where these efforts are failing. Give it a shot on your own (you obviously know how to write some code) then let us know where it's not working and we can help. SO is not a "code for me" service. Read more in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Scott - I do a lot of research and am definitely not after free code without putting the legwork in. I have code which copies other data from the workbook into selected ranges on another sheet but can't see a clean way of doing the same but splitting it in the process.  Maybe there isn't one. I'll put some code below with what I do with a single sheet copy.

Comment: there's definitely a way, you just have to do 4 separate value transfers (or copies), 1 for each column needed (x's the number of sheets needed).

Comment: If I try to keep it in a single sub I have a feeling the code could get very messy.  I'll try the route of splitting into temporary sheets first to check that works ok and then see if there's a way of pulling it back into a single sheet.